# ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey violation with dependent destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have this models:

User model

```rb
has_many :photos, inverse_of: :user, dependent: :destroy
```

Photo model

```rb
belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :photos
```

And in my controller I want to do something like this:

```rb
User.where(...).destroy_all
```

I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey
PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  update or delete on table "users" violates foreign key 
constraint "fk_rails_d873b4f337" on table "photos"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(491234) is still referenced from table "photos".
: DELETE FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1
```

Why do I get this error if I have `dependent: :destroy`?

Comment: Not that it's causing your problem, but since you are not using any weird naming conventions you shouldn't need the `inverse_of` in your definitions. The has and the belongs_to should automatically try to match up through the class names.

Comment: Can you add your DB schema for the two models? It is the DB that is blocking the delete, not Rails itself. Maybe add the applicable migration code for the two models.